# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value') error when trying to DeserializeObject using JsonConverter .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to Deserialize Object from API response to return it in my API call, an async call but I'm getting this error:

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')

and from the iis express debug

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

my code is

```
 private static async Task<dynamic> Post(string url, string request)
    {
        var content = new StringContent(request.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var data =  await Client.PostAsync(url, content);

        string response = await data.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        dynamic responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);

        if (bool.Parse(Startup.StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("Debug")))
            Logger.Info("Request: " + request);
        //Logger.Info("Response: " + response);

        return responseObject;
    }
```

any ideas ?

Comment: It would help to see the request as well as the exception stack trace.

Comment: @mobh13 Have you checked to see what is being returned into `string response`???

Comment: Two ideas: 1. Debug and find the exact row that throws the exception. 2. Stop abusing `dynamic`.

Comment: thank you all after removing the try and catch i figured it out , one of you guys kindly add an answer to make it as the correct answer the bool.parse was making the issue

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I understand **bool.Parse** was the issue probably because the "Debug" value was null.

If it should be impossible for that value to ever be null then throwing an exception is fine here as your application should probably explode if something like this occurs.

If there is a possibility during normal operation that "Debug" will not have a value use **bool.TryParse** instead as this will allow you to wrap an if statement around a successful parse and simply ignore the value if it does not exist, and potentially set yourself a safe default.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for Content NULL:

```
    if(data.Content != null)
    {
       string response = await data.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

       dynamic responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
    }
```